# An upper bound of $ \left| \frac{1}{s}\log\zeta(s) \right| $ for $\Re s=\sigma>1$, from this integral formula and a related comparison

Tags: asymptotics, improper-integrals, analytic-number-theory

For $\Re s=\sigma>1$ one has the following known formula $$\frac{1}{s}\log\zeta(s)=\int_1^\infty \Pi(x)x^{-s-1}dx,$$
then if we take the derivative we can write $$\frac{1}{s}\log\zeta(s)=s(s+1)\int_1^\infty \Pi(x)x^{-s-2}\log x dx-s\int_1^\infty\frac{\psi(x)}{x^{s+1}}dx.$$

I would like to do a comparison between my computations with the best/relatively good upper bound of $$ \left| \frac{1}{s}\log\zeta(s) \right| $$ for $\Re s=\sigma>1$.

I say with these computations, where I use the **Prime Number Theorem** or the fact, that is a consequence of this theorem, that  there exists superior limit of $\frac{\pi(x)}{x/\log x}$ as $x\to\infty$, we take this as a constant about $1.11$. We can use the triangle inequality to get 
 $$ \left| \frac{1}{s}\log\zeta(s) \right| \leq  1.11\cdot\left| (s+1) \right| + \left| s(s+1) \int_1^\infty\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{\pi(x^{1/k})}{kx/\log x}x^{-s-1}dx\right| $$ $$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad+\left| s\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\psi(x)}{x^{s+1}}dx\right| .$$

> **Question.** Can you compute upper bounds for the second and the third summand, using only this kind of statements, I say the Prime Number Theorem or its consequences?

I know that for example for the third summand one has $$\left| s\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\psi(x)}{x^{s+1}}dx\right| \leq |s|\int_1^{\infty} \frac{2\psi(x)}{x^{\sigma+1}}dx,$$ 
and $\psi(x)=x+o(x)$. Can you finish my computations from this way, and refers us on the other hand a good upper bound of  $ \left| \frac{1}{s}\log\zeta(s) \right| $ for $\Re s=\sigma>1$? **Many thanks.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? Let $s = \sigma + it$ with $\sigma > 1$.
$$\zeta(\sigma) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^\sigma} \leq 1 + \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^\sigma} \, dx = 1 + \frac{1}{\sigma - 1}.$$
Then
$$|\log \zeta(s)| \leq \log \zeta(\sigma) \leq \log\left(1 + \frac{1}{\sigma-1}\right) \leq \frac{1}{\sigma-1}.$$

Comment: Is very much simple that my approach, and I understand all details,

Comment: If you are looking for a good online resource to learn analytic number theory, consider this: http://www2.math.uu.se/~astrombe/analtalt08/www_notes.pdf

Comment: Very thanks much, I will see the notes. On the other hand I have more books in house that courage to read them. Thanks much.